# Cannot reset a select in material css

Tags: angularjs, material-design

My HTML code is like this

```
<div class="input-field">
    <select ng-model="user.place">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose The Region</option>
      <option value={{value}} ng-repeat="value in region">{{value}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

- When the page loads up the select option "Choose The Region" is shown.
- Now select any region.
- Now I want to reset the select back to "Choose The Region"

I have tried to do `user.place=''` but this does not work! I am clueless on how to reset the select box.

Comment: Can you paste your data?

Comment: In my controller init i am doing
$scope.region = ["Somalia", "Middle East", "Threat Network Nigeria", "Niger", "Libya", "Mauritania", "Cameroon", "Kenya", "Azerbaijan", "Greece", "Kosovo", "Cyprus", "Sicily", "Malta", "Bosnia", "Herzegovina", "Turkey", "Georgia", "Central African Republic"];
The select Box come properly with values in it.
We can select the values.
The issue is that it does not reset.

Comment: Hi Cyril. Mine was a good edit, in which I removed the extraneous backticks, removed the unnecessary ellipsis marks and added inline formatting. You should regard improvement edits as a favour and not an attack on your work. I will be reverting this back, and if I see it is undone again I will be flagging for a moderator. I am still happy to continue the discussion on the other thread.

Comment: @halfer Hey you seem to be changing my question and answers as per your will...i don't approve off your help my questions are very clear and I am sure technical people will understand that. Can you please leave me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the obvious thing?

`<option value="" disabled selected>Choose The Region</option>`

`^^^^^^^`

**disabled** attribute would explain why you cannot select it.